# __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) when trying to define custom base test class

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, inheritance, class-hierarchy

I defined in `CustomTestCase.py` file:

```
class CustomTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest'):
        super().__init__(methodName)

        self.example_file_name = ...
        self.example_file_path = ...
```

Then I defined in `test_plot.py` file:

```
import CustomTestCase

class TestPlotMethods(CustomTestCase):

    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest'):
        super().__init__(methodName)

    def test_plot_skel(self):
```

and got

```
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

at `TestPlotMethod` line.

Traceback is following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pycharm-2017.2.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1599, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/opt/pycharm-2017.2.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1026, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/opt/pycharm-2017.2.1/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/opt/pycharm-2017.2.1/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py", line 35, in <module>
    main(argv=args, module=None, testRunner=unittestpy.TeamcityTestRunner, buffer=not JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 93, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 140, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 147, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 219, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 219, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 153, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "<MYPROJECTPATH>/src/test/python/test_plot.py", line 13, in <module>
    class TestPlotMethods(CustomTestCase):
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: Yes it is Python 3. I am very familiar with OOP in other languages, but here I actually just don't understand what I am doing.

Comment: Why are you even defining an `__init__` method for `TestPlotMethods` if it doesn't do anything of its own?

Comment: Are both of your classes defined in the same module? The exception message suggests to me that something weird may be going on (since it mentions `module.__init__`). Can you give the full traceback?

Comment: Include the full error traceback

Comment: `super()` in Python is a bit special, as it doesn't *necessarily* invoke the method on the superclass, but the *next method in line*, according to MRO (method resolution order). That difference usually only starts to matter with complex inheritance hierarchies like diamond inheritance, which I'm not seeing in your case. But I'd still highly recommend [Raymond Hettinger's talk "Super considered super!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) to clear up what exactly `super()` does.

Comment: This is actually not reproducible on my side. I copy-pasted this exact same code, with `import unittest` at top and `unittest.main()` or `TestPlotMethods()` at the bottom. WAI. Although it is kinda a bad practice to overwrite `__init__` of unittest when you have both `setUp` and `setUpClass` methods.

Comment: @FunkySayu agreed, cannot reproduce either.

Comment: @Blckknght probably you re right; see my update please.

Comment: This isn't Java. You don't need to, and shouldn't, name your files the same thing as the classes they contain.

Comment: @user2357112 ah got it, this is name clash between class and file...